# How to dynamically set the overflow on the body of an AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to dynamically set the overflow on the body of my AngularJS app. I have a sidenav that opens up and when it is open I want to disable scrolling on the body. If someone could have a look at my code and give me some hints on how to achieve this, that would be great:

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="backgroundCtrl as background" md-theme="blue-grey" ng-style="{'overflow-y': background.lockBackgroundTrue}">
```

Controller:

```
    controller('backgroundCtrl',function(){
        this.lockBackgroundFalse = 'auto';
        this.lockBackgroundTrue = 'hidden ';
    });
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If this is not possible alternative methods would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have added ng-style for that purpose ?

Comment: It's working fine :).I tested it with http://plnkr.co/edit/zVL1eurGVltbMyWW1lTR?p=preview.Check the style on the body.

Comment: I hope you are not missing `app` word in `app.controller` in code

Comment: Yup squiroid you were 100% right. Thanks I dont know how I didnt think of checking there. Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Okay that actually didnt work. The lockBackground values are getting passed correctly but it still allows a scroll. However if I set the style normally as style="overflow-y:hidden" it does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about adding something like `style="overflow:{{isEnabled?'hidden':'scroll'}}"`.

A more *angular-way* would be doing `ng-style="{'overflow':isEnabled?'hidden':'scroll'}"`

You may set `isEnabled` on ng-click accordingly.

```
   <button href="#" ng-click="isEnabled=false">Enable scroll </button>
   <button href="#" ng-click="isEnabled=true">Disable scroll</button>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/0UITA2ca8V60vYAKIUA2?p=preview)

Cheers!

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you very much. Can anyone expand on why it would work with style but not ng-style?

Comment: It works with ng-style aswell. You just need to take care of right syntax. See updated answer :)